# zsh array assignment and no match errors

Tags: zsh

zsh version 5.2

I'm attempting an array assignment using filename generation like so:

files=(/some/path/*/dir/myfile)

Indeed this is the way the zshoptions manual recommends to achieve what I want.

When no matches exist I want the array to be empty.  Instead it's producing

**no matches found: /some/path/*/dir/file**

and the script terminates.

I've tried setting NULL_GLOB, CSH_NULL_GLOB and ensured NOMATCH is not set.

When matches do exist it works as expected.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance,

Wayne

Answer (score 3):

Well of course I found the solution after posting my question.

For this to work EXTENDED_GLOB needs to be set as well as NULL_GLOB. Or a glob qualifier can be used so that NULL_GLOB only effects this particular expansion.

This is how to set NULL_GLOB for a single operation:

**files=(/some/path/*/dir/myfile(N))**

Hope that can help someone else who encounters this.

Wayne